# Cannot make reference to Facebook SDK project

Tags: android

I am tryin to integrate Facebook in my Android app.
In some tutorials, I see that I must make a reference to base Facebook project.
I try this and all looks like must be: [here](http://i53.tinypic.com/vkehl.png)
After that I open properties again and here is result: [here](http://i51.tinypic.com/29yjtzc.png)
There is no connection between the projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the Facebook Lib project in your eclipse workspace is/stays open. Otherwise the library won't be found.

**This is correct:**

[image]

**and this throws an error since the project is closed:**
[image]

Comment: Sorry i didnt understand. What you mean with "project in your eclipse workspace is/stays open"?

Comment: I mean maybe you closed the project in the package explorer. See the screenshots I added. (did that mistake by myself the first time, that's how i get to it :) )

Comment: No this is not a problem.Actually i find the solution:I must move facebook project to location of my project.

Comment: If you found the solution to your problem, please post it for others as a seperate answer. Lots of people come here via search engines, this might help them if they have a similar issue. Thanks! :)

Comment: Solution was simple: Referenced project must be in one base directory.If not projects cannot establish connection together